# How to make ctags + scss play nice

Tags: css, vim, sass, ctags

**UPDATE:**
This question has been modified to reflect the very helpful comments and answer below. I've accepted the answer, but the full functionality is not working to-date.

Contents of .ctags (in ~/)

```
-R
--exclude=.git
--exclude=log 
--verbose=yes
--langdef=scss
--langmap=scss:.scss
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*([^\t {][^{]{1,100})(\t| )*\{/| \1/d,definition/
--regex-scss=/^[@]mixin ([^ (]+).*/\1/m,mixing/
```

When I place my cursor under the target, vim says `E426 tag not found: tag_name`

Consider the following pattern:

```
footer{
 .wrapper{
  .general-info{
   .footer-links{
     a{@include ticker($bg, $white);}
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

In a separate file (modules.scss) in the directory, I have the definition for ticker:

```
@mixin ticker($color, $bg-color) {
 color: $color;
 background-color: $bg-color;
}
```

When I place my cursor under the target, vim still says `E426 tag not found: tag_name`

ctags does not index the `ticker` mixin. However I can use ctags to find methods from SCSS gem directly (e.g. darken).

Comment: with the example you provided the regular expression I gave you works for me. If the cursor is in the word ticker and I press `ctrl+]` it jumps to the first line where ticker is defined in modules.scss. Also the line with the word definition is not doing anything there right now, I don't think that line generates valid tags, you can delete it. The work mixing is just a way of labeling the tags so they could be grouped (if you would configure the taglist plugin then all the tags labeled mixing would be listed together.

Comment: you are right. I had to refresh my ctags in the directory. lesson learned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding a `\` before the last `{` gives no warning when using ctags.
I don't know if the tags produced give the desired result since I don't know the language.

The result would be:

```
--langdef=scss
--langmap=scss:.scss
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*([^\t {][^{]{1,100})(\t| )*\{/| \1/d,definition/
```

Update: like I mentioned above, I don't know the language, so it is hard to check the actual definition of the tags.
I looked online and the following code is listed as scss in some webpage.
Suppose the tags you want to get are the words following mixing.

```
@mixin table-scaffolding {      
  th {                          
    text-align: center;         
    font-weight: bold;          
  }                             
  td, th { padding: 2px; }      
}                               

@mixin left($dist) {            
  float: left;                  
  margin-left: $dist;           
}                               

#data {                         
  @include left(10px);          
  @include table-scaffolding;   
}
```

then with the following:

```
--langdef=scss
--langmap=scss:.scss
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*([^\t {][^{]{1,100})(\t| )*\{/| \1/d,definition/
--regex-scss=/^[@]mixin ([^ (]+).*/\1/m,mixin/
--regex-scss=/^[@]function ([^ (]+).*/\1/f,function/
```

you get the two new tags `left` and `table-scaffolding`.
So if I am in the word `left` inside data hit `ctrl+]` it jumps to the line where data is defined.
You have to be careful for the other keyword because it has a `-` in the word. So if you are on table and press `ctrl+]` you will get the same error tag not found. For this to work you have to add the following in your `.vimrc`

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

You should be able to generalize the above for other tags you need, or even build a general regular expression to handle all the tags, as you initially meant.

If you post a specific example of how the file you are trying to work with looks like, and what are the tags you are trying to obtain I am sure I or other people would be able to help figure out a expression for that.

Comment: the question was about getting it to work not suppress warnings. SCSS is a meta-framework for writing css syntax.

Comment: well, do the tags you get match what you expect?

Comment: I am still not getting the desired result, but I am able to now pick up .scss methods from the gem I use. what does `mixing` and `definition` mean in the line? Also I added the specific example, apologies!